# objectify.LoadException: java.time.LocalDateTime must have a no-arg constructor

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Java 8 `LocalDateTime` class to persist date in the datastore. 
The date is this format `2017-07-24T01:00:00.000` is persisted as an EmbeddedEntity.

```
private LocalDateTime matchDateTime;
```

The persistence flow is alright. But when I load the entity exception is thrown.

```
com.googlecode.objectify.LoadException: Error loading : java.time.LocalDateTime must have a no-arg constructor
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load(EntityMetadata.java:78) ~[objectify-5.1.21.jar:na]
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine.load(LoadEngine.java:185) ~[objectify-5.1.21.jar:na]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.time.LocalDateTime must have a no-arg constructor
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.getNoArgConstructor(TypeUtils.java:47) ~[objectify-5.1.21.jar:na]
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.construct(ObjectifyFactory.java:69) ~[objectify-5.1.21.jar:na]

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.time.LocalDateTime.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

How do I fix this?

I researched & added in my pom.

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Marked the date property with

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime matchDateTime;
```

but still it doesn't workout. Any guesses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Objectify does not have builtin support for the J8 data types. However, you can add support in your app very easily.

Look in the Objectify source for the package `com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.opt.joda`. It contains the translators that allow Objectify to use joda time objects; you register these with the `ObjectifyFactory` before registering your entity classes. It should be apparent how they work; you just need to be able to convert between `LocalDateTime` and however you want it stored in the datastore.

A bit of warning: Do not be tempted to convert `LocalDateTime` into a `java.util.Date`, which represents an instant in time. Your `LocalDateTime` has no TZ and therefore is not an instant. It's best to represent this as the ISO 8601 string. Look at `ReadablePartialTranslatorFactory`... although the reflection is probably unnecessary for your use case.

Comment: Any progres on this? What about new versions?

Comment: `Instant` is supported since the datastore has builtin support for timestamps. LocalDateTime you will need a custom translator for. Look at the InstantTranslatorFactory. I assume you want it to be an iso8601 string in the datastore?